# Problems during the test of In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit, mkstorekit

Im trying to implement In-App Purchase. The code is ready (Im using the framework MKStoreKit 4.0) but I cant test it, I always get an error.

My application is not 100% ready. So I just created the application on itunesconnect without submitting source code.

My app status is "Prepare for Upload" and my In-App Purchase status is "Ready to submit".

Its possible to test In-App Purchase at this point? Or I have to do something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

RafCad

Comment: Do you have provision profile directky for you appID? InApp don't work with profile like "com.somesite.*"

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting. It is impossible to tell what your problem is without more information.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help.

The error that I was getting: "Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product"

But after following the steps on this page: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/It started working. I think that the problem was related with the step 5 from the link.

Thank very much for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that I was getting:

```
Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product"
```

But, after following the steps on this page:
[troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) it started working.

I think that the problem was related with the step 5 from the link.